# Todays date always highlighted on ajax calendar extender

Tags: ajax

I have an ajax calendar extender, but there is a problem. Todays date is always highlighted no matter what, so if i go to pick a date it comes out as this:

todays date/d/year

And no matter what date i pick it will always end up as the chosen date is todays date, then the month as the date you picked?

which i dont want...

Can anyone help me please?

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDOB"></asp:CalendarExtender>

            <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" MessageValidatorTip="true" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true" CultureName="en-GB"

              Mask="99/99/9999" 
              MaskType="Date"
              AcceptNegative="None"
              TargetControlID="txtDOB"


             />

             <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender1" ErrorMessage="Incorrect date" 
             ControlToValidate="txtDOB" 
              EmptyValueMessage="Date is required"
            InvalidValueMessage="Date is invalid"
            Display="Dynamic"
            TooltipMessage="Input a date"
            EmptyValueBlurredText="*"
            InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Invalid date"

             >

             </asp:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i have solved it, it was due to one of those weird glitches that i experience once in a while with visual studio. Simply copying and pasting the code in again, and it was working.